# sort and extract certain number of rows from a file containing dates

Tags: perl, awk

i have in a txt file, date like:

```
yyyymmdd
```

raw data are like:

```
20171115
20171115
20180903
...
20201231
```

They are more than 100k rows. i am trying to keep in one file the "newest" 10k lines, and in a separate file the 10k "oldest" 10k lines.

I guess this must be a two steps process:

1. sort lines,
2. then extract the 10k rows that are on top, the "newest = most recent dates" and the 10k rows that are towards the end of the file ie the "oldest = most ancient dates"

How could i achieve it using awk?

I even tried with perl no luck though, so a perl one  liner would be highly accepted as well.

Edit: i would prefer a clean clever solution so that i learn from,
and not an optimization of my attempts.

example with perl

```
@dates = ('20170401', '20170721', '20200911');
@ordered = sort { &compare } @dates;
sub compare {
    $a =~ /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
    $c = $3 . $2 . $1;
    $b =~ /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
    $c = $3 . $2 . $1;
    $c <=> $d;
}
print "@ordered\n";
```

Comment: Yes, this would be easy in Awk or Perl. `sed` has no concept of sorting, though a masochist could reimplement `sort` in `sed` if they really wanted to waste time.

Comment: so i remove sed from my question, thank you

Comment: We would still expect to see your attempts so far.

Comment: Is the input sorted, like in your example?

Comment: no, to make the question smaller, more readable, my example looks like the desired output

Comment: is there a sorting requirement within the 2 final data sets, eg, the 'newest' is sorted in descending order? the 'oldest' is sorted in ascending order? what is the structure of the final data sets ... files? (`bash`) arrays? something else?

Comment: I just noticed that you put the day first, month second and year last. How is that going to sort them in the order you describe?

Comment: `@ordered = sort @dates;` would have been sufficient in the Perl snippet

Comment: That is a horrible sort subroutine for the Perl code. Why would you reverse the date? That will just break everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your lines with dates will sort lexicographically, it is simple. Just use `sort` then `split`.

Given:

```
cat infile
20171115
20171115
20180903
20100101
20211118
20201231
```

You can sort then split that input file into files of 3 lines each:

```
split  -l3 <(sort -r infile) dates
# -l10000 for a 10,000 line split
```

The result:

```
for fn in dates*; do echo "${fn}:"; cat "$fn"; done
datesaa:
20211118
20201231
20180903
datesab:
20171115
20171115
20100101

# files are names datesaa, datesab, datesac, ... dateszz
# if you only want two blocks of 10,000 dates, 
# just throw the remaining files away.
```

---

Given you may have significantly more lines than you are interested in, you can also sort to a intermediate file then use `head` and `tail` to get the newest and oldest respectively:

```
sort -r infile >dates_sorted
head -n10000 dates_sorted >newest_dates
tail -n10000 dates_sorted >oldest_dates
```

Comment: If the files are big, writing out a lot of data you don't actually care about is probably going to introduce significant I/O overhead over a simple script which only extracts and writes the top and bottom ten numbers.

Comment: Use `head` and `tail` then.

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl).
If you want the oldest on top, you can use the standard sort order:

```
@dates = sort @dates;
```

Reverse sort order, with the newest on top:

```
@dates = sort { $b <=> $a } @dates;
#                  ^^^
#                   |
# numerical three-way comparison returning -1, 0 or +1
```

You can then extract 10000 of the entries from the top:

```
my $keep = 10000;
my @top = splice @dates, 0, $keep;
```

And 10000 from the bottom:

```
$keep = @dates unless(@dates >= $keep);
my @bottom = splice @dates, -$keep;
```

`@dates` will now contain the dates between the 10000 at the top and the 10000 at the bottom that you extracted.

You can then save the two arrays to files if you want:

```
sub save {
    my $filename=shift;
    open my $fh, '>', $filename or die "$filename: $!";
    print $fh join("\n", @_) . "\n" if(@_);
    close $fh;
}

save('top', @top);
save('bottom', @bottom);
```

Comment: could you please provide me with a working full solution, since the above helps, but i would like from say 121.000 rows, take in the top array the first 10.000 items, and in the bottom, again the 10.000 items

Comment: @pesaw What should be done with the 101000 items that are not among those 10000+10000? Should they be thrown away?

Comment: yes, they are not useful for my report

Comment: @pesaw Ok, this should do it then

Answer (score 2):

A command-line script ("one"-liner) with Perl

```
perl -MPath::Tiny=path -we'
    $f = shift; $n = shift//2;              # filename; number of lines or default
    @d = sort +(path($f)->lines);           # sort lexicographically, ascending
    $n = int @d/2 if 2*$n > @d;             # top/bottom lines, up to half of file
    path("bottom.txt")->spew(@d[0..$n-1]);  # write files, top/bottom $n lines
    path("top.txt")   ->spew(@d[$#d-$n+1..$#d])
' dates.txt 4
```

Comments

- Needs a filename, and can optionally take the number of lines to take from top and bottom; in this example `4` is passed (with default `2`), for easy tests with small files. Don't need to check for the filename since the library used to read it, [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny), does that
- For the library (`-MPath::Tiny`) I specify the method name (`=path`) only for documentation; this isn't necessary since the libary is a class, so that `=path` may be just removed
- Sorting is alphabetical but that is fine with dates in this format; oldest dates come first but that doesn't matter since we'll split off what we need.   To enforce numerical sorting, and once at it to sort in descending order,  use `sort { $b <=> $a } @d;`. See [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort)
- We check whether there is enough lines in the file for the desired number of lines to shave off from the (sorted) top and bottom (`$n`). If there isn't then that's set to half the file
- The syntax `$#ary` is the last index of the array `@ary` and that is used to count off `$n` items from the back of the array with lines `@d`

This is written as a command-line program ("one-liner") merely because that was asked for. But that much code would be far more comfortable in a script.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- dates are not unique (per OPs comment)
- results are dumped to two files `newest` and `oldest`
- `newest` entries will be sorted in descending order
- `oldest` entries will be sorted in ascending order
- there's enough memory on the host to load the entire data file into memory (in the form of an `awk` array)

Sample input:

```
$ cat dates.dat
20170415
20171115
20180903
20131115
20141115
20131115
20141115
20150903
20271115
20271105
20271105
20280903
20071115
20071015
20070903
20031115
20031015
20030903
20011115
20011125
20010903
20010903
```

One idea using `GNU awk`:

```
x=5

awk -v max="${x}" '
    { dates[$1]++ }
END { count=0
      PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_desc"      # find the newest "max" dates
      for (i in dates) {
          for (n=1; n<=dates[i]; n++) {
              if (++count > max) break
              print i > "newest"
          }
          if (count > max) break
      }
      count=0
      PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"       # find the oldest "max" dates
      for (i in dates) {
          for (n=1; n<=dates[i]; n++) {
              if (++count > max) break
              print i > "oldest"
              }
          if (count > max) break
      }
    }
' dates.dat
```

**NOTE:** if duplicate date shows up as rows #10,000 and #10,001, the #10,001 entry will not be included in the output

This generates:

```
$ cat oldest
20010903
20010903
20011115
20011125
20030903

$ cat newest
20280903
20271115
20271105
20271105
20180903
```

Comment: dates are not unique... but i like your approach

Comment: @pesaw updated answer to support duplicate dates

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty Awk attempt which collects the ten smallest and the ten largest entries from the file.

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { for(i=1; i<=10; i++) max[i] = min[i] = 0 }
NR==1 { max[1] = min[1] = $1; next }
(!max[10]) || ($1 > max[10]) {
    for(i=1; i<=10; ++i) if(!max[i] || (max[i] < $1)) break
    for(j=9; j>=i; --j) max[j+1]=max[j]
    max[i] = $1 }
(!min[10]) !! ($1 < min[10]) {
    for(i=1; i<=10; ++i) if (!min[i] || (min[i] > $1)) break
    for(j=9; j>=i; --j) min[j+1]=min[j]
    min[i] = $1 } 
END { for(i=1; i<=10; ++i) print max[i];
print "---"
for(i=1; i<=10; ++i) print min[i] }' file
```

For simplicity, this has some naïve assumptions (numbers are all positive, there are at least 20 distinct numbers, duplicates should be accounted for).

This avoids external dependencies by using a brute-force sort in native Awk. We keep two sorted arrays `min` and `max` with ten items in each, and shift off the values which no longer fit as we populate them with the largest and smallest numbers.

It should be obvious how to extend this to 10,000.

Answer (score 0):

Same assumptions as with my [other answer], except `newest` data is in ascending order ...

One idea using `sort` and `head/tail`:

```
$ sort dates.dat | tee >(head -5 > oldest) | tail -5 > newest

$ cat oldest
20010903
20010903
20011115
20011125
20030903

$ cat newest
20180903
20271105
20271105
20271115
20280903
```

OP can add another sort if needed (eg, `tail -5 | sort -r > newest`).

For large datasets OP may also want to investigate other `sort` options, eg, `-S` (allocate more memory for sorting), `--parallel` (enable parallel sorting), etc.